# "No ST-LINK detected" error message, when trying to connect with ST-LINK Utility

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, openocd

I have a [NUCLEO-F401RE board](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f401re.html) (with [STM32F401RE](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-high-performance-mcus/stm32f4-series/stm32f401/stm32f401re.html))
and it has been working fine for the most part. Here recently, I followed a tutorial in the book "[Mastering STM32](https://leanpub.com/mastering-stm32)" where it says to install [OpenOCD](http://openocd.org/).

I had been following along before this as well, and I had been able to connect to my board and flashing it without any problem.

After attempting to get OpenOCD to work though, this is no longer possible. Every time I try to connect to my board, I simply get the following error message:

> No ST-LINK detected

I have tried updating the drivers multiple times, rebooting the board, reinstalling the [ST-LINK](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html) utility, switching the USB cable, resetting the board and reinstalling everything and I have also tried the trick where you hold down the reset button and try to erase the chip.
So far, none of this has worked for me unfortunately.

Here is a picture of my board:

[image: A picture of the Nucleo STM/ARM development board STM32F401RE]

On my desktop, I am using Windows 10. On my board, and I am using [FreeRTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeRTOS).

Here is an image of my Windows [Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager):

[[image: Screenshot of Windows Device Manager, with the USB controllers' part expanded9]

I have also tried to update the firmware on my board using the ST-LINK  upgrade, but without any luck. When attempting this, I either do not have the option to select my device (when using the *.jar* application) or when using the *.exe* application, I just get the following error messages:

> No ST-Link device detected 
> Please connect it and then retry

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: (1) Have you actually retried the previous toolchain after closing OpenOCD things, disconnecting/reconnecting your nucleo board? (2)  I'm not sure what can learn from the experience updating STlink firmware using different .jar/.exe apps. Could you please some more detail on this part? (3) Additionally, could you please tell us if the (user part of) board changed its behaviour after you have started to work with OpenOCD?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in other answers, the problem is almost certainly due to a competing driver (something like libusb) taking control of the device.

However, you do not need to "uninstall and reinstall everything" to select the correct driver, assuming that you have already installed it once before. Moreover, the reinstallation procedure most likely won't help, because the uninstallers usually do not uninstall the drivers anyway, and Windows will keep prefering the same wrong driver.

Instead, open Device Manager, find your STM32 STLink device, double-click to open the Properties dialog. Then click "Update Driver", then "Browse my computer for driver software", then "Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer", and you should see something like that:

[image: Driver list]

You see that in this example, at least four different drivers available on the system are happy to service the device. The first two are generic libusb drivers, not specific to the dongle (OpenOCD is happy to use either of those, if I remember correctly). The ST-Link utility, however, wants a dedicated driver, developed by STM - those are the two entries below on my picture. If you do not see those, try installing the ST-Link utility again (no need to uninstall anything) or download just the [driver](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-utilities/stsw-link009.html) from the STM website.

You can now click on the preferred driver in this list and have it replace whatever driver was assigned to the device before.

Comment: Thank you. Downloaded the drivers `en.stsw-link009` and windows scanned this directory and I successfully managed to find device in STM32 ST-Link Utility. This should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

From my poor experience the "No ST-LINK detected" message in the STM32 Utility shows when you are disconnected or when other program is using a ST-LINK. So, if this start happens after installing OpenOCD try to uninstall this and try again (maybe with option "Connect under reset"?).

For your information. When you plug the cable to the PC and the board is power on then in the settings (STM32 Utility) you can see available ST-Links (even blocked). [Here is example when ST-Link is blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsQGC.png)

Answer (score 1):

From what I have learned and understood (but everyone can correct me :)), your board is divided in two parts:

- The ST-Link debugger part;
- The rest with the actual microcontroller.

The ST-LINK part is used to flash the microcontroller and can be used to flash any other STM32F4 device through [SWD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG#Similar_interface_standards). With your picture:

[image]

The STM32 ST-LINK Utility uses the ST-LINK part of your board to flash it. My point is that if you have the "No ST-Link detected", the issue, I am quite sure, doesn't come from the microcontroller part, but comes from the ST-LINK part. And since you did say that it worked before you install OpenOCD, I would suggest the driver part in Windows 10 that may be the root of your problems.

Try to uninstall everything (and I mean **everything**) related to the STM32 (OpenOCD, STM32 ST-Link Utility and its driver through *Device Manager*).

Reinstall only the STM32 ST-Link utility (if you did uninstall the drivers correctly, it should ask you the permission to install the drivers during set up) and try to connect your board.

You can also try to remove the SWD jumpers (connector *CN2*) on your board to detach the ST-LINK from the built-in microcontroller part. Since the ST-LINK part is independent it will still be detected by the STM32 ST-LINK Utility (but you will have to put the jumpers back if you want to actually program your microcontroller).

Comment: Thank you very much for your heIp! think you are definetly correct regarding the point about the drivers. To further support this theory, I have actually got the same board working on another computer, so it must be on my PC.

I just tried to reinstall everything, and as you pointed out - **everything**. This, unfortunately, yields no result still. 

I will have to look further into removing the SWD jumpers, and see if that has an effect.

Comment: Have you tried to use the faulty board on your other computer to see if it is detected ? Or to use your working board on your W10 computer ?

Comment: Is the corresponding USB port still OK? And, since this question is nearly 3 years old - does that computer still exist?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this. The problem boiled down to using Nucleo boards and trying to interface with them using older versions of ST-LINK (ST's search for ST-LINK's first hit led me to *stsw-link0004*, which was not installing the right drivers).  Why they don't point you to the latest greatest first, who knows.

Whenever I tried to install drivers, I could only select USB Composite device as a compatible driver, despite repeatedly uninstalling/reinstalling stlink0004.

You need to install the newest ST-LINK, e.g., stsw-link0009 (or newer).

1. Uninstall device ([Device Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) had it under USB Composite Device)
2. Uninstall ST-LINK
3. Disconnect the Nucleo.
4. Reboot.
5. Install ST-LINK (stsw-link0009)
6. The prompt should have you install three or more drivers.  Not just two.
7. Plug in. Voilà.